# I want my custom Error type has name "Error"

Tags: swift, swift5

Not "MyError" or with any other prefixes or suffixes. I want it to be just "Error". Because when I refer this type in the code it would be like: `MyApp.Error`. Nice and simple.

```
enum MyApp {
    enum SomeModel {}
    enum OneMoreModel {}
    enum Error: Error {
        
    }
}
```

It does't compile:

> 'Error' has a raw type that depends on itself

I tried `Error: swift.Error` but

> Cannot find type 'swift' in scope

What else can I try?

Comment: Did you try "`Swift.Error`" with a capital `S`?

Comment: @Sweeper Yea, thank you, it works! Just what I need. If you provide your answer in form of a post I'll be able to exact it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the module is [`Swift`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift), with a capital "S".

```
enum Error: Swift.Error {
    
}
```